# iOS tableview multiple sections

Tags: ios, tableview, rows, sections

i am having a problem with the below code on iOS, i have 3 sections and each section has a certain number of rows which is defined by the function: countcells.

But each time i run it i have the same error: 
2014-07-29 22:16:32.710 TYM-APP[5598:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

What's wrong with the code??

```
  - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
   return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   if (section == 0)
   {
       NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT count(*) FROM homedata where module_ID= 77"];
       return [self countcells:querySQL];
   }
   else if(section == 1)
   {
       NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT count(*) FROM homedata where module_ID= 78"];
       return  [self countcells:querySQL];
   }

   else if (section == 2)
   {
       return[self countcells:@"SELECT count(*) FROM homedata where module_ID= 81"];
   }
   else return 0;
}


- (int) countcells: (NSString *)query
{
   int e;

   NSString* text;
   NSString * paths=[self getWritableDBPath];

   const char *dbpath =  [paths UTF8String];
   sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
   static sqlite3 *database = nil;

   if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
   {
      NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:query];

      const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

      //  NSLog(@"Databasae opened = %@", userN);

      if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,
                           query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
      {

         while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
         {
            text = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *)     sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            e = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
            NSLog( @"Valeur directe: %d", e);
         }
         //  username.text=@"No Username";


         sqlite3_finalize(statement);
      }
      //  NSLog( @"Save Error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database) );
      NSLog( @"Count Value: %@", text);
      sqlite3_close(database);
   }

   return e;
}
```

Comment: Yikes! Those table methods are called over and over. Do the queries once and save the results. Opening and closing the db so many times is terribly inefficient as is doing those queries over and over needlessly.

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: it isn't entering the first and second condition. it is only entering the third condition (if section ==2 ) and crashes there. as for section = 0 and section = 1 it is not accessing them

Comment: i fixed something but now the error is index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]. in the storyboard i created a table with 3 sections. Is should be working no?

Comment: Once again - which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: Can you add `Exception Breakpoint` and tell where it stops.

Comment: Are you sure it is not somewhere around `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndePath:` delegate method?

Comment: ok, i finally got it to work. turns out i have to change the tableview type to dynamic prototype.

Answer (score 1):

int e has garbage value. make sure it should be >= 0 value.